# Sexpect run telegram-cli commands script

Tags: bash, sockets, pipe, telegram, sexpect

I would like to use `sexpect` to run `telegram-cli`.
For example, I would like to see all the unseen messages and run the `dialog_list` command.

I have sexpect in the `path` and `telegram-cli` inside `tg`.

```
if ! which sexpect >& /dev/null; then
    echo "sexpect not found in your \$PATH"
    exit 1
fi

export SEXPECT_SOCKFILE=/tmp/sexpectProva.sock
sexpect spawn -timeout 2 -nowait tg/bin/telegram-cli
notRead="$(sexpect expect -cstr -re '*[\r\n]')"
echo "${notRead}"

dList="$(sexpect send dialog_list)"
echo "${dList}"

rm /tmp/sexpectProva.sock
```

This is the output:

```
Telegram-cli version 1.4.1, Copyright (C) 2013-2015 Vitaly Valtman
Telegram-cli comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show_license'.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `show_license' for details.
Telegram-cli uses libtgl version 2.1.0
Telegram-cli includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project
for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
I: config dir=[/home/ale/.telegram-cli]
>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I don't understand how should I use the `.sock` file.

Comment: please post the output of your manual interaction with the command and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: or you better first try with commonly used commands so other people can aslo try and help.